# Visual Studio WInForms Designer Images from Resources file

Tags: image, winforms, visual-studio-2015, resources, designer

When I set the Image property of a Button control to point to an image in the Projects resource file, it shows up just fine in the application when I compile and run it, but if I try to load the form in the designer, it gives me an 3error message.

> The type 'CoP.LAS.Properties.Resources' has no property named
>   'Adobe1'.

Although when I look in the auto-generated Resources file,  it is clearly there:

```
namespace CoP.LAS.Properties {
  using System;


  /// <summary>
  ///   A strongly-typed resource class, for looking up localized strings, etc.
  /// </summary>
  // This class was auto-generated by the StronglyTypedResourceBuilder
  // class via a tool like ResGen or Visual Studio.
  // To add or remove a member, edit your .ResX file then rerun ResGen
  // with the /str option, or rebuild your VS project.
  [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute(
      "System.Resources.Tools.StronglyTypedResourceBuilder", "4.0.0.0")]
  [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
  [global::System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute()]
  internal class Resources {

    // Other stuff...

    /// <summary>
    ///   Looks up a localized resource of type System.Drawing.Bitmap.
    /// </summary>
    internal static System.Drawing.Bitmap Adobe1 { // <--- HERE!!!
        get {
            object obj = ResourceManager.GetObject("Adobe1", resourceCulture);
            return ((System.Drawing.Bitmap)(obj));
        }
    }
}
```

And the designer will not load the form unless I ignore this error, which removes the setting from the form code. The only way I have been able to fix this is to import the graphic into the project for each place in the project where I want to display it. This is, obviously redundant, as the image is being "imported" for every usage. I should be able to use images in the project's common resource file and still load the form into the designer.
What's going on here and how do I fix this.

Comment: I had something similar in the past  so i added images as embedded resources: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984367%28v=vs.71%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Yes, that's how I'm working around the issue, but I think that is embedding the resource once for each place where it is used, obviously a redundant waste of storage.